# My question was unclear and closed, but I have edited it and it has not been reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596376/only-match-url-beginning-with-www-or-https) 5 days ago that wasn't so clear to understand, so it was put on hold within one hour. I understand that action.

Next day, I realized how bad the question was, so I read about [how I can reopen my closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) and tried following the steps. I started [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25596376/revisions) my question, and after my edits, I've got 3 reopen votes, till today when my question status changed from [on hold] to [closed]. The last step listed was "ask on Meta", so I am asking here in the hope that I will get the answer as to what I am still doing wrong.

I still don't know why no one wants to reopen the question. Is there something else unclear, or is there something what I have forgotten to do?

Comment: You'll have to wait :P ... But after checking your question's edit history, you didn't edited anything essential there as you were told to do. So most people will leave it closed.

Comment: I thought the question will no longer be in reopen review if it is flagged as closed.

Comment: Hooray for the system working - it's always nice to see on-hold questions getting reopened (eventually) due to editing on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's always been flagged as closed.  The difference between "closed" and "on hold" is a UI issue only, designed to give people hope about the editing/reopening process.

Evidently that worked, you thought submitting some edits was worthwhile.  And now you've seen it on the way out of closure due to reopen votes being cast.

But your question still wasn't answerable, because you still hadn't specified what inputs should be matches and what shouldn't.  So while you might pick up some reopen votes from people who want to reward you for editing a bad question instead of flaming the voters, your editing work isn't done yet.

Based on the information that's missing, it's quite likely you need to do some more thinking first as well.  We can't read your mind, and we sure can't figure out business requirements if you don't know them either.

But don't give up just because it says (closed) instead of (on hold).  There is no difference, except that the longer you wait to edit, the fewer people will actually see your changes and the harder getting 5 reopen votes will be.

Now that you've put in a real rule ("match URL beginning with `www` or `http(s)://` and nothing else"), it becomes possible to help you.