# What is difference between "On Hold" and "Closed" questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions, on-hold

Can we edit our closed questions? If we edit the question well then is the question reopened by the Stack Overflow community? I have read the 'Help Center' and I learned 'Closed' and 'On Hold' questions have the same properties. But what is the real difference? Closed and removed questions are editable. But I wonder can they be reopened?

Answer (score 35):

"On Hold" and "Closed" are fundamentally the same thing. Both mean that the question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow either because of its content or quality.

"On Hold" is the wording used immediately after the question is closed and implies that the state is less permanent than "Closed". This is because it doesn't have to be the final state of the question. If the question can be improved and/or brought on topic by good editing then there's a chance it will be reopened. After 5 days the wording changes to "Closed".

While the question is in the "On Hold" state, edits will put the question onto the reopen review queue where other members of the community can see if it's now a good question.

For more information see:

> [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582)

and:

> [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

Comment: I wonder - *is* the state less permanent than "Closed"? Are questions genuinely more likely to be reopened in their first 5 days after closure?

Comment: @MarkAmery - edits during this period put the question on the reopen review queue where people *will* see it.

Answer (score 14):

Copied from the MSE FAQ [What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/158100)

> ### What does it mean for a question to be *closed*?
>
> When a question is closed, no additional answers may be posted to it, although the question and existing answers can still be edited (by users with edit privileges or by suggested edit) and voted upon, and will continue to count for badges. The asker of a closed question may still accept an answer.
>
> Closed questions can be re-opened by users who have sufficient reputation.
>
> ### What does it mean for a question to be *on hold*?
>
> If a question has been closed, then for the first 5 days, it is marked as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During this period, if the question is edited <s>by the asker</s> ([now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196026/nobody-in-my-community-has-the-power-to-re-open-a-question#comment618477_196026) by anyone), it will be added to the [reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). Other than this, there is no functional difference between “on hold” and “closed”.

### Can we edit our closed questions?

Yes, and you really should. Use the edit link under your question to add the details that are asked for in the close reason or visit (and study):

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

When you have a reputation of 5 or more you can also ask on meta how you can improve your question. Examples of such questions are [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269273/how-can-i-improve-my-first-ever-stack-overflow-question), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287368/is-this-a-valid-stack-overflow-question-and-if-so-how-might-i-improve-it-so-it) and [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270818/my-question-was-unclear-and-closed-but-i-have-edited-it-and-it-has-not-been-reo) but don't do it like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316451/request-to-open-my-question) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317895/please-read-my-comments-on-top-of-your-commments-before-dismissing-it-all-togeth).

When you have a reputation of 20 or more you can also enter [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and enter a toolstack/technology specific room or visit the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room, which has a focus on moderating posts.

### If we edit the question well, is the question reopened by the Stack Overflow community?

If your question is edited, on-topic and matches the community quality guidelines your question gets a re-open review task where 5 users will judge if you have done a good job.

Remember that editing also *bumps* the question, meaning it gets renewed attention on the active tab of the question list. That will bring fresh eyes and possible re-open voters to your question.

**tl;dr** On hold/closed questions are like invitations for the question author to improve their question with substantial edits that carefully address the issue(s) raised. When the improvements are successful the question has a better chance being re-opened.