# Request to open my question

Tags: support, answers, comments, downvotes

It is so important for me to get an answer of this question. Maybe my question is having a long answer, but it is understandable to all. I am not asking for full explanation over there. Just give me a URL where I can read the tutorials. If my question will be unanswered and kept on-hold then how can I develop my skills? All who is a master today were newbies someday, but they were guided in a good way.

Please open my question and at least give me some link or other website address where I can get a better answer. My question is *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246661/how-to-create-cms-like-wordpress-using-codeigniter-3-0-and-hmvc*.

Comment: `If my question will be unanswered and kept on-hold then how can I develop my skills` the usual way, by doing research yourself. That's how most of us here developed their skills.

Comment: Nope.  This isn't the place to ask for tutorial recommendations.  Those kinds of questions are specifically off-topic here.  If you want to ask something like that, go to reddit or some such thing.

Comment: It's not a good question by the standards of this community. Sorry.

Comment: *"It is so important for me to get answer of this question"* - but **only to you**. *"Just give me a URL where I can read the tutorials"* - finding resources for people is explicitly off-topic, can't you use a search engine?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Wait, you mean you didn't learn how to program by asking other people to do all of your work for you?  But that's so much easier than the alternatives!

Comment: @Servy I know, right? Had I only waited until 2009!

Comment: Did you read the banner? Your question won't be reopened it's off-topic. Your edit didn't actually help it's just off-topic for a different reason now: _Asking for a tutorial, book or other 3rd party resource ..._  Please check the help center what can be asked here.

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil People are downvoting your question instead of answering it because you asked an extremely low quality question that isn't appropriate for this site.  Had you looked at the site's rules (which you were required to do before posting the question) you'd have known that.

Comment: What everybody thought that I didn't googled, I did, but do you know what I got, I got each and every thing in partial, Like if the tutorial taught about Codeigniter and HMVC then it is missing the Templating Engiens, If they are Teaching about Codeigniter+ Smarty then they are missing HMVC, I also went through multiple tutorial about Codeigniter HMVC+Widge they are missing Templating. The fact is no one is trying to understand my real proble everyone is following one other, If someone down voted then you should too....

Comment: "but do you know what I got" No, because you didn't tell us until now. The reason no one is trying to understand your problem is because you don't even give us a chance to do so.

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil The fact that you did a google search first doesn't make your question on topic for the site, or automatically mean that it's a quality question.

Comment: Is there any written rule for that, I am not a GOD who reads mind and Human Psycology, and not only me lots of developers are facing this type of problems but due to down votes or anything else, they are not trying to get the specific answer, THink again is it a bad Question, In behalf of Down Votin anyone can ask me the thing that, What type of problem you are facing. That's it, I will make him my question clear

Comment: @Servy I am not telling that my my question is a very quality question but, Is this community is for those who is are experienced or any newbie can ask there silly question after lots of serches made?

Comment: `I am not a GOD who reads mind and Human Psycology` you don't need to be. Just read the faq.

Comment: oooo dear, don't try to make me understand all those things, can you prove that, prove that the question should not be asked here? on any strong base not verbally, Eery technical question is not fueled with codes, some questions are in pargraph also, Go and read the question again think twice that what should be answer,.

Comment: It's in the faq. I'm not going to dig up the correct reference for you, got other things to do.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: not that he's interested anyway. See the first sentence.

Comment: I edited my question now please suggest me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246661/codeigniter-3-0-hmvc-codeigniter-widget-library

Comment: *"Having problem to integrate widget library and call widget."* That's not a problem statement. It's a statement that you have a problem, but tells us (almost) nothing about the actual problem. Also, like most sentences than end in `.` rather than `?`, it does not ask a question.

Answer (score -24, accepted):

I completely get the idea of following the standards, but this kind of elitism makes me not want to be a part of the community. The personality or misunderstanding of the asker isn't the key here. If you respond to SO questions, you put yourself in the position of being the teacher. Responses of "you suck at asking questions" or "you can't follow the rules" are pointless and not constructive.

The original topic should have been closed, not deleted. Otherwise, there's no way for others to learn from it. The meta should have been closed without response. Now we're just school-yard bullies ganging up on the kid in the back of the class.

Comment: I don't disagree this could have been handled more neutrally by Meta folk (myself included). I also hate rampant deletionism... although any educational effect from that question staying non-deleted would likely have been minimal.

Answer (score 28):

No, your question is not being re-opened, it even got deleted.

Your question  didn't meet the criteria for being on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Keep in mind that this site doesn't exist to find tutorials for you, write a program for you or fix a bug for you.

The members of this community are investing their time in questions and answers that are useful for **FUTURE** visitors because that makes the internet a better place for the millions, not only for you.

If you want to have a great time here we expect the questions to be well researched (and which results turned up, and how didn't each of them work for you when you applied them), show effort from the OP, have a clear problem statement and can have an answer that doesn't require a project team to create.

You better head back to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and use the [CheckList](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for your next question.

Comment: ooo dear thank you so much for your better answer, But remember that every question is asked when their is lots of effort made to get the answer and still the question remain unanswered,On what base you all are saying that my question is inappropriate? because I am asking for tutorial,. look inside you Do you have any answer for that very question if you have then make your point strong by proving it.

Comment: Don't have any idea how to prove that the question should not be asked here? You all follow each other and using all your powers on a wrong place, That's it......Don't even do such things.......I will get the suitable answer of my question and re ask and answer my question.... so that if any one have the same problem they can get the answer.

Comment: @Alok that question would be likely to be deleted also. The community simply doesn't want broad "I want to do X" type questions because historically, they've been causing too many problems.

Comment: Dear that is not my question, that is my question body, If i will edit my question removing I want to, then will it be enough to answer it.

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil what aren't you getting? I suggest you take some time to read the material in the help center and lurk to see what kind of questions get positive responses before asking again, otherwise there is likely to be a question ban in your near future.

Comment: I edited my question, Now please suggest me the correct thing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246661/codeigniter-3-0-hmvc-codeigniter-widget-library

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil *"having problem"* isn't a question, give a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or, to put it another way, stop whining and RTFM.

Comment: 'Do you have any answer for that very question if you have then make your point strong by proving it' - It's difficult to believe that, after getting a -42 shafting here on meta, you decide to try again to get an answer to your question.  How many times does it have to be said?  Your question is no more. It has ceased to be. It's expired and gone to meet its maker. It is a late question. It's a stiff. Bereft of life, it rests in peace. If you hadn't nailed it to the chat, it would be pushing up the daisies. It's rung down the curtain and joined the choir invisible. It is an ex-question.”

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Rene and since you don't want to click the links,

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.